# htaccess don't redirect easy url and php page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

First of all, I apologize. I looked up a lot of questions but so far nothing has worked. I don't know why.

I have a site www.mysite.it

and one URL is

```
www.mysite.it/home.php?pagina=home
```

I want to see

`www.mysite.it/home` or `www.mysite.it/home.php` is the same

I added this in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ home.php?pagina=$1
```

and I have this expression in my php:

```
<?php 
$get= @$_GET ['pagina'];
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 'home') . '.php';

    if(file_exists($get)){
        include($pagina);
    } else {
        include("404.php");
    }

 switch ($get){
            default :
            include ('contenuto/home.php');
            break;

            case "tournament":
            include ('torneo/torneo.php');
            break;

            case "arena":
            include ('contenuto/modalita/arena.php');
            break;
```

etc

Comment: How is this not working?

Comment: I think it should be `switch($pagina)` instead of `switch ($get)`

Answer (score 1):

Your RewriteRule only matches URLs that end with "/". You'll need to change your rewrite rules. Consider using an R directive as well as L.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ home.php?pagina=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?pagina=$1 [L]
```

Then change your logic. The 404 if block should go below case. It seems like you're figuring out what page you're going to at multiple places. I tried to sort that out below. Also, use the debug statements to determine if the variables are getting set how you want them. Also remember that pagina must match an actual file on the disk, including directory. For example, if you ask for torneo, it won't be found. tournament only works because it has a special listing in the switch block.

```
$get = @$_GET['pagina'];
if (!isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
    $get = 'home';
    $pagina = 'contenuto/home.php';
} else {
    $pagina = $get . '.php';
}

// debug
echo $get . '//' . $pagina

switch ($get) {
        default :
        $pagina = 'contenuto/home.php';
        break;

        case "tournament":
        $pagina = 'torneo/torneo.php';
        break;
}

if (file_exists($pagina)) {
    include($pagina);
} else {
    include("404.php");
}
```

Comment: no if i try to write `http://www.mysite.it/home/` in my browser he put me out:
`Not Found

The requested URL /home/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: Not necessarily conclusive - you sometimes return a 404 from your script. What happens with `http://www.mysite.it/home/` and file_exists($pagina)

Comment: thanks for the answere, home.php , torneo.php, ecc is a part of the page in my site not a page itself this is why I include all of this block, this $pagina is the body of my dynamic page

Answer (score 0):

Here you check for the existence of one file and you include another :

```
if(file_exists($get)){
    include($pagina);
```

This cannot work. It must be :

```
if(file_exists($pagina)){
    include($pagina);
```

Comment: @scribo What do you mean by loading with no result ?

Comment: If i correct with your code my site don't load on my browser

Comment: I didn't expect it to work. Your code doesn't make sense. I just pointed out one of the problems. What you have to do is look at your error log or set display_errors on.

Comment: Ok unfortunally i write only the html & css part, another person write the php part but i don't have contact anymore.